# Что изучает Литература?

Tags: литература, образование

Школьный предмет обычно является продолжением какой-то науки. А наука что-то изучает, систематизирует - то есть у неё, в свою очередь, есть свой *предмет*. У биологии - живые организмы, у арифметики - числа, у русского языка - гм... ну, скажем, значения слов и правила построения предложений...

Каков предмет "науки" *литература* в школе? "Лишний человек"? История смерти Пушкина? Политические взгляды Некрасова? - Это как бы всё история и отчасти психология. Имеет ли вообще право на существование отдельный предмет *литература*?

=== UPD to [[[[@Hermit](/users/1954/hermit)](/users/1954/hermit)](/users/1954/hermit)](/users/1954/hermit): "Моделирование жизненных ситуаций" не является спецификой именно литературы (это вам скажет любой специалист по тренингам). "Приёмы художественной выразительности", пожалуй, могут быть предметом изучения литературы (хотя в такой же степени и лингвистики), но их с гулькин нос, и курс такой "литературы" должен был бы уложиться максимум в один год.

=== UPD to [[@Инна](/users/466/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0)](/users/466/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0): вымученный (предмет) - составителями школьной программы: заставляют читать в пятом классе какого-то нудного и бездарного "Тараса Бульбу", когда дети ещё не прочитали "Незнайку на Луне", "Винни Пуха" и "Шляпу гроссмейстера".

Лицемерный - потому что пытается *безапелляционно* учить (что хорошо и что плохо) не от чистого сердца, а от страха перед начальством (день за белых, день за красных).

=== UPD to [[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7): "Особенности текста в общекультурном контексте" - в этом, безусловно, что-то есть. Но такой науки применительно к современным текстам, безусловно, не было и в помине, когда я учился в школе и в вузе. Официально не существует её и сейчас, потому что материал для неё только ещё накапливается - на таких сайтах, как http://lurkmore.to/

---

=== UPD В общем, ответ более-менее ясен (по крайней мере, мне):

1) научным предметом Литературы в школе в некоторой степени являются выразительные средства языка ([[[[@Hermit](/users/1954/hermit)](/users/1954/hermit)](/users/1954/hermit)](/users/1954/hermit));

2) основные задачи Литературы в школе - не изучать что-то, а вырабатывать навыки:

а) навыки чтения и вкуса, привычки к хорошей речи ([[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f));

б) умение выражать свои мысли ([[@Сергей Богорадо](/users/1750/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE)](/users/1750/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE)); понимать чужие тоже сюда подойдёт ([[@русак](/users/2323/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BA)](/users/2323/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BA)).

Comment: Имеет. Кроме знакомства с приёмами худож-й выразительности в словесном описании реальности лит-ра в школе служит, прежде всего, "Сборн. задач и упражн. по модельному представлению жизненных ситуаций". Как и история. Как бы ни был широк круг общения и поведения молодёжи, лит-ра даст гораздо больше примеров для осмысления и формирования собственного мировоззрения. 

Конечно, без общ. идеологической красной нити её преподавание не обходилось во все времена. Плюс общ. бюрократизация всей страны... 
Вот дефицит искусства маневрирования среди этих подводных камней и даёт то, что есть на самом деле.

Comment: Вы бы лучше ответом оформили. Отвечаю в вопросе, а то комментариев, чувствую, не хватит...

Comment: Вы против изучения литературы в школе?

Comment: "Почему не уважаю, - смутился Незнайка. - Уважаю. Только я не знаю, какая она, эта ваша частная собственность".

Я не знаю пока, против я или нет. Не уверен. Потому и вопрос. Но я всю школу терпеть не мог этот вымученный, лицемерный, нудный предмет. А в университете так просто взненавидел его. А сейчас вот вспомнил об этом (здешние вопросы навеяли).

Comment: Кем вымученный? Почему лицемерный? А "нудность" или её отсутствие зависит от учителя

Comment: По моему мнению, Литература изучает пустое множество. Научный коммунизм изучает пустое множество тоже, но с другой стороны.

Comment: Ну что Вы (говорите)? Пустое множество - это "Лунная соната" для человека, лишённого музыкального слуха, а для остальных - пустое? И литература тоже не пустое для большей части людей. А Научный коммунизм - на любителя, как Археология, Палеонтология, Уфология и проч.

Comment: Ну что Вы (говорите)? Научный коммунизм затрагивает интересы в десятки раз большего числа людей, чем Лунная соната. А насчёт литературы... "Большей части людей" только __кажется__, что литература для них не пустое множество; "большая часть людей" знает о науке _литература_ гораздо меньше, чем о научном коммунизме.

Answer (score 7):

> Школьный предмет обычно является
> продолжением какой-то науки

Вовсе не обязательно. Музыка, изобразительное искусство, трудовое обучение, физкультура - никакого отношения к науке не имеют. Литература - искусство слова. И уроки литературы знакомят с этим искусством. В школьном предмете "Литература" соединились разные аспекты литературного образования: это и  история литературы, и литературоведение.

Кроме того, трудно переоценить роль уроков литературы в развитии речи ребенка. 
Не секрет, что сейчас дети в семьях читают очень редко. Они даже редко смотрят телевизор. И получается, что хорошую речь  дети слышат прежде всего в школе, и прежде всего - на уроках литературы. Которых, кстати, в среднем звене, всего ДВА урока в неделю. Даже прочитать все не успеваем на уроке. А дома большинство детей не читают. А если и читают заданное, то не понимают элементарных слов. И уроки превращаются в уроки литературного чтения с переводом с русского на русский. Так что уроки литературы - это прежде всего уроки развития речи. Это уроки чтения, уроки знакомства с произведениями классической и современной литературы, уроки культурного образования и "образовывания" человека.

Прав и  Hermit в том, что, читая литературные  произведения, ребята ставят себя на место героев произведений, учатся вести себя в той или иной жизненной ситуации, понимать, что хорошо, а что плохо.

Comment: Что - "вовсе необязательно"? школьный предмет _обычно_ НЕ является продолжением науки? это НЕобычно для школьного предмета?

Про "уроки литературного чтения с переводом с русского на русский" - зачёт. Я бы дубиной заставлял читать по 100 страниц в день всех учеников поголовно (ну, и родителей до кучи). Назывался бы ещё урок __Чтение__, и моего вопроса бы не было.

А вот слышат ли дети _именно на этих уроках_ "хорошую речь", совсем не очевидно. Не замечал, что речь учителя литературы "лучше" речи учителя истории или математики.

Comment: О науке: я имела в виду, что литература - не наука, а искусство. Искусство слова. Не сомневаюсь, что учителя истории и математики, а так же других предметов хорошо говорят. Не передергивайте. Я и сказала, что дети связную грамотную речь слышат, в основном, в школе. И разве я сравнивала учителей разных предметов? Я имела в виду речь не только и не столько учителя, сколько речь со страниц литературных произведений.

Comment: Да, кстати, я Вас поддерживаю, уроки литературы, по сути, и являются уроками литературного чтения. А если и не являются, то должны. И даже если снова увеличат количество часов, основное на уроке - чтение и осмысление прочитанного.

Comment: Я лишь полемически заострил про "хорошую речь". Там ведь есть и другая сторона. Если мы говорим о "хорошей печатной" речи, так ведь тексты учебников истории в этом плане так же хороши, как и "литературные". И третья... про учителей я как раз имел в виду противоположное: _обычно_ речь учителей недостаточно хороша (и литературы, и математики), неуклюжа. Хороший оратор - большая редкость.

Да, нужно ещё добавить, что хороший учитель вовсе не обязан быть хорошим оратором. Я встречал немало великолепных "молчаливых" методистов, не умеющих и не любящих много и пространно рассуждать.

Comment: Верю. И очень понимаю.

Answer (score 3):

Предметом изучения для гуманитарных наук в школьном образовании является *условная схема человеческого поведения в условных обстоятельствах*. Именно эти условные схемы, по большей части и изучают дети на уроках литературы, истории, обществознания, МХК и пр.

Причина подачи именно таким способом вызвано тем, что в гуманитарных науках для того чтобы увидеть процесс, нужно знать огромное множество частностей, в то время как для точных наук характерна скорей обратная картина (процесс мы видим, а почему так происходит - нужно разбираться). Изучая гуманитарные науки, ребёнок получает возможность увидеть варианты поведения людей в той или иной ситуации, что в дальнейшем должно помочь ему адаптироваться в "мире людей".

Науки же, изучающие вроде бы те же самые предметы, что и школьники (история, культурология, литературоведение) по сути занимаются теми проблемами, которые школьник оценить в силу возраста не в состоянии. Лишь в старших классах у учителя появляется возможность продемонстрировать ученикам краешек этих наук, но и то на самом примитивном уровне.

---

Stopkran, написать второй ответ, возможно только если кто-то преобразует твой комментарий в ответ. Если нужно именно моё мнение, могу ответить по почте (указана в профиле).

Comment: _но и то на самом примитивном уровне_ - вот это в точку. На том уровне, который доступен им самим. Даже на этом форуме никто пока не назвал специфического предмета литературоведения (ну, кроме "выразительных средств"). Определяя предмет, сущность литературы как _условную схему человеческого поведения_, вы делаете литературу подразделом психологии и отказываете ей в праве на отдельное существование.

Comment: _которые школьник оценить в силу возраста не в состоянии_ - а вот это вы вывели из ложной посылки (определения литературы через психологию).

Человек, способный решить квадратное уравнение и выделить деепричастный оборот (7-й класс), обладает достаточным интеллектом, чтобы отличить анапест от ямба (одна из _собственно-литературных_ задач).

Comment: Стихотворные размеры стиха - это из литературоведения, что тоже входит в область школьного предмета "Литература". Я об это говорила, Вы невнимательны. (Это к замечанию о собственно-литературных задачах). Вопрос не для нашего форума. Слишком объемен.

Comment: @stopkran, ямб от хорея школьник, если с ним "побиться" ещё сумеет отличить, и тропы найти тоже в состоянии. Но выделить особенности текста в общекультурном контексте, особенно если этот текст отстоит от нас во времени, школьник не сможет. Тоже самое касается выделения и систематизации факторов влияющих на восприятие текста (Вишневый или Вишнёвый сад).

В первом предложении комментария у меня отсылка к строкам Пушкина, но чтобы её обнаружить нужно быть со мной в одном культурном контексте.

Comment: >Определяя предмет, сущность литературы как условную схему человеческого поведения, вы делаете литературу подразделом психологии и отказываете ей в праве на отдельное существование.

@stopkran, я говорю о школьном курсе, а не о науке. Под это же определение попадает и история, и МХК, и обществоведение. То что изучают на уроках истории не имеет почти никакого отношения к науке "история".

Comment: На прошлом допросе, гражданин, вы показали, что литература изучает "условные схемы человеческого поведения...". "Особенности текста в общекультурном контексте" - это уже совершенно иная статья! Дальше отвечу в вопросе (из-за лимита комментариев). Да, может быть, вы напишете на эту тему второй ответ? (чтобы можно было продолжить обсуждение)

Comment: @stopkran, я указал, что в школьном образовании изучают условное поведение условного человека. Литературоведы же изучают текст в культурном контексте. В старших классах школы в примитивном виде дают позаниматься и собственно предметом науки (сочинения на тему "образ героя в произведении" и подобные), но в целом наука остаётся за школьным курсом.

Литературоведение как раз и рассматривает текст в контексте, а "Лурк" лишь фиксирует более-менее современные мемы (необязательно вербальные) в контексте интернет-культуры. Непосредственно тексты сайт не рассматривает.

Answer (score 1):

Главный недостаток наших школ заключается в том, что учителя не говорят и зачастую не могут объяснить, зачем ученику в будущем понадобится изучение данного предмета. Главная цель предмета "Литература" - научить владеть пером, т.е научить излагать свои мысли на бумаге: научить писать книги, письма, жалобы, заявления, обращения, воззвания, докладные (пояснительные и служебные) записки, инструкции... итд итп.

Comment: Для того, чтобы научиться писать, необязательно обращаться к художественной литературе. Достаточно на уроках русского языка изучить грамматику текста и практически закрепить свои знания написанием рефератов по истории, географии, общественным наукам. Смысл художественной литературы - это передача знаний через человеческие эмоции. Как сказал наш великий классик, "О, память сердца! Ты сильней Рассудка памяти печальной".

Comment: А как научиться писать книги, если не обращаться к уже имеющемуся опыту цивилизации? А как научиться писать стихотворения, не читая лучших поэтов? Да и рефераты по истории или географии - это переработка уже имеющихся текстов, которые кто-то уже написал в определённом стиле, и это тоже нужно уметь.

Comment: Вот это в точку. Только я бы убрал определение "на бумаге". Просто - излагать свои мысли. Ну, и добавил бы к литературе язык, что-то вроде этого: __главная цель уроков словесности - научить излагать свои мысли__.

Comment: Пожалуй, я возражу. **Первая главная цель уроков словесности -  научиться (правильно!) понимать: книгу (писателя), учителя, товарищей, научиться адекватному восприятию мира**. **Вторая - Ваша цель**. **А третья (по К. Марксу) - наметить план по переделке мира**:"Прежние философы лишь различным образом объясняли мир, а задача состоит в том, чтобы переделать его" (цитата не точная)

Answer (score 0):

1. Для чего нам нужна литература

Когда настоящий художник слова рисует разнообразные картины жизни – природу, людей, их поступки, события, почему нам это интересно? Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, попробуем сравнить наше восприятие  действительных и придуманных событий.

Вот мы видим мир реальный, ощущаем его, он вызывает в нас различные переживания – так рождаются чувственные, затем  мысленные образы. А вот мы читаем  художественную литературу – и там  всё наоборот: уже слова и мысли вызывают эмоции, но они могут быть такими же яркими и насыщенными, как  и при реальном контакте с действительностью. «Порой опять гармонией упьюсь, Над вымыслом слезами обольюсь…»

Можно сказать, что мир эмоций находится посередине: с одной стороны  –  реальность, с другой – мысли и слова, и они одинаково  успешно могут воздействовать на чувства. Трудно представить нашу жизнь без добрых сказок и смешных историй в детстве, без пушкинских стихов, без классических романов.  А где-то рядом  рождается и сосуществует с нами  литература новая, рисующая  наш мир. Опыт человеческого существования   с помощью изящной словесности  становится несравнимо более широким, и кем-то придуманная  жизнь влияет на жизнь настоящую гораздо в большей степени, чем мы думаем.

2.Как мы изучаем литературу в школе

В школе литература начинается с чтения, но тут же к прочитанному материалу задаются вопросы, нас просят пересказать текст. Читать было интересно, а обсуждать скучно? Вот здесь  и начинается мастерство педагога. Можно задать такие вопросы, так построить обсуждение, что это будет не менее интересно, чем само чтение.  Мне очень нравится театр в школе – от небольших зарисовок до вполне серьезных постановок. Самое главное – не надо забывать об эмоциях, потому что в противном случае  от изучения литературы будет немного  пользы.

Но дальше – больше, начинается анализ произведений. И опять всё зависит от учителя и его методик: иногда  прочитав хороший разбор стихотворения, понимаешь, как это интересно, насколько поверхностно ты понимал его раньше, как мало знал о поэте и его жизни. Кажется, что на твоих глазах  художественное произведение из плоского превращается в объёмное. Очень показателен в  этом отношении анализ  художественного пространства пушкинского  «Евгения Онегина», когда вместо не слишком сложной сюжетной линии  наше внимание переключается на внутреннее понимание человеческой жизни во всем ее многообразии.

3.Почему не всем нравятся уроки литературы

И всё-таки часто можно услышать негативные высказывания об уроках литературы. Мне кажется, очень сильно мешает формальный подход, стандартные схемы, обязательные требования. Хотелось бы, чтобы учителю литературы  предоставляли больше возможностей для свободного творчества, для импровизации.  И главное – нежелательно иметь перечень «правильных» мыслей, так как читатель, по большому счету, является соавтором произведения и имеет право на собственное мнение. А основным критерием  для оценки знаний по литературе должно стать умение учащегося грамотно излагать свои собственные мысли. Не раскрыл тему – это значит не смог доказать свое мнение, а не мнение кого-то другого.

Comment: Да нет никакого перечня правильных мыслей. И мнение учителя вполне может не совпадать с традиционным. А мнение ученика вполне может не совпадать с мнением ребенка. И, поверьте, никто оценок за это не снижает. Учителя только рады, когда ребенок рассуждает.

Comment: Да проблема ведь вовсе не в том, что ученику навязывают чужие мысли. Проблема как раз в том, что его заставляют высказывать свои. А когда их (своих) нет - это __насилие__ (целые сочинения __ни о чём__ писать!). Представьте, что вас заставляют высказывать мнение по предмету, который вам совершенно незнаком и не интересен, - не просто мнение, а развёрнутый рассказ, по определённым правилам! Видимо, отсюда идёт моя глубоко укоренившаяся ненависть к урокам литературы.

Comment: Да, урок литературы и сама литература очень разнятся. Личность учителя, личность писателя и личность ученика не могут быть однотипны. Отсюда проблемы преподавания предмета и восприятия его учениками. Тем не менеее, литература в школе нужна, потому что самостоятельно (особенно теперь) мало найдётся таких, кто добровольно будет читать художественные книги. А без литературы дети превратятся в подобие роботов. В роботизированном обществе не будет родины, морали, сострадания и проч. Но, видимо, тогда же прекратятся и войны в том виде, в котором мы знаем теперь о них. Прогнозировать трудно.

Answer (score 0):

> Лицемерный - потому что пытается безапелляционно учить (что хорошо и что плохо)

Может быть, так было в прошлом веке. Сейчас "модно" интересоваться мнением ученика.

> вымученный (предмет) - составителями школьной программы: заставляют читать в пятом классе какого-то нудного и бездарного "Тараса Бульбу", когда дети ещё не прочитали "Незнайку на Луне"

Должо быть в 7-м. И не совсем нудного. А красота природы? А патриотизм и предательство?

Comment: Насчёт "не совсем нудного" - слабое утешение. В мире существует огромное множество (не пустое!) великолепных, захватывающих дух литературных произведений. Тратить время на чтение "не совсем нудных" попросту жалко.

Comment: Диалог: Скажи нам, Петя, что ты сам думаешь о Чацком? - Ничего.
Чтобы Петя имел мнение, нужно много поработать над этой задачей, а не только интересоваться.

Comment: над какой задачей и кому - поработать? учителю над Петей, Пете над Чацким?

По-моему, и то и другое - утопия. Экономически выгодней привлечь Петю к работе над Холмсом (или над Штирлицем) - достаточно лишь слегка подтолкнуть, и работа сама покатится.

Comment: Господи, а завуч-то причем? У нас есть школы, в которых интерпретация литературного произведения зависит от мнения завуча???? Тогда мне очень повезло со щколой.  Я вообще не понимаю, как связаны завуч и страх. Помните,  в советские времена был лозунг:
"Совесть - лучший контролер". Так вот для учителя, на мой взгляд, самый лучший контролер - это дети.

Comment: Вам-то хорошо говорить, с высоты своего опыта. А молодым учителям как? "Интерпретация", которая не вступает в конфликт с мнением <strike>партии</strike> методобъединения, - это не интерпретация, а шаблонное унылое ге. Я, конечно, утрирую. Потому что в большинстве случаев молодые специалисты думают о Чацком то же самое, что и Петя (и для них мнение методиста - палочка-выручалочка).

И да, дети вам наконтролируют. Если бы у них была такая возможность, вы бы только Гарри Поттера с ними на уроках читали. Гм, это в лучшем случае. А в худшем - смотрели бы "Феечек" на планшетах.

Comment: Дети очень хорошо понимают, что должен и чего не должен делать учитель. И если я буду "Смотреть "Феечек" на планшетах", это им понравится только первый раз, ну второй. А потом скажут, что учительница такая же пустоголовая, как и они, ничего не знает и не умеет. 

А завуч уже давно не методист, а человек, умеющий хорошо отписывать бумажки в гороно. Он, может, и методист, только заниматься ему этой работой некогда. 

Да, школа - тема неисчерпаемая. Да и школы очень разные.

Answer (score 0):

> Литературоведы же изучают текст в культурном контексте ([[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7))

Когда и где? Я когда-то сам учился на филфаке, я помню: не было там никакой текстологии. Была болтология и бесконечное тупое чтение с пересказами. Внимательно посмотрел программы главного (вроде бы) вуза страны: http://www.philol.msu.ru/for-students/workplans/ - тоже ничего похожего.

Под "литературой" (особенно в школе) обычно понимают "художественную литературу" (ХЛ). Я здесь придерживаюсь такого же понимания. Если существует какая-то наука, использующая материал ХЛ, она должна поставить ХЛ в ряд других Л (текстов) или И (искусств) и изучать то, что делает тексты ХЛ особенными, отличными от других видов текстов (например, юридических) и отличными от других видов искусств (например, музыки или архитектуры).

В каком веке написан *Декамерон*? *Робинзон Крузо*? *Остров сокровищ*? А читать так же увлекательно, как и современный *Ночной дозор*. Какое значение имеет тут исторический "общекультурный социоконтекст"? Как говорит [[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F), ну звук, ну фонема - какая разница?

В ХЛ значение имеет только одно - интересно читать или нет. Вот этим и должна заниматься "литературная наука" - отличать качественные произведения от бездарных, изучать Художественные Образы, благодаря которым произведение получает "вечную жизнь". Что делает того же "Тараса Бульбу" вымученным и каким-то подражательным, а "Портрет" великолепным и гениальным?

Comment: Н. В. Гоголь был очень сложным человеком. Как, впрочем, и каждый из нас. Но ТБ не вымучен, он написан на одном дыхании. Заметно, что Гоголь любил всех их, о ком писал, и подозрение о вымученности, на мой взгляд, не оправдано. А подражательность? Кому? Вот вопрос. "Портрет" и "Портрет Дориана Грэя" - что лучше? Я раздваиваюсь в выборе лучшего. "Портрет" и ТБ - очень разноплановые произведения, у них нет общего знаменателя, кроме таланта писателя. "Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке" и "Аленький цветочек" - обе читаются с интересом, но "Сказка" более весома в воспитательном плане. ТБ и "Портрет" - тоже.

Comment: Это Гоголь-то нудный? Так можно кого угодно в нудные записать.

Comment: Ну, пусть не нудный. Унылый. И не Гоголь, а Тараз Бульба. Не нравится он мне, вот тебе и весь сказ. А "Портрет" - блестящий.

Comment: А фильм по  "Тарасу Бульбе" Вам тоже нудным и унылым показался? А ведь практически по гоголевскому тексту.

Comment: Если честно, просто не помню. Наверняка ведь смотрел в детстве (если фильм старый и типа "боевик"), но вот ни следа не осталось. Старого "Вия" хорошо помню (фильм) - осталось довольно сильное впечатление (такое же унылое, как от книги "Тарас Бульба").

Comment: Я говорю о фильме Бортко 2009 года.

Comment: Конечно, есть и у Гоголя книги с плохим концом. Эта концовка всегда оставляет негативное впечатление и многих вводит в уныние, как говорится, осадок остался, перечитывать не хочется. Тогда читаем "Ревизор"!

Comment: Вроде "Портрет" тоже не очень хорошо кончается?

Comment: Да, плохой конец ни при чём. У Короля Лира, в конце концов (каламбурчик такой), тоже плохой конец, но книга мощная. И через строки "Портрета" на нас смотрит Мастер.

-------------

Унылая, вялая скука эти ваши ТБ, вот в чём дело - ни сюжета нормального, ни языка; никак и ни о чём, как будто заказ чей-то выполнял (а уж детям в школу такое давать - только вражеским). Фильм 2009 года не видел (и, видимо, не увижу - из-за сильной аллергии на книгу).

Comment: Единственное произведение, где Гоголь обратил внимание читателя на свою фамилию, назвав в конце ТБ птицу "гоголь". Любил он казачество! Как виртуоз, играл на струнах патриотизма. Дал волю в художественном тексте своим религиозным чувствам. Уже тогда он увидел сегодняшний Майдан! И, наверно, плакал бы, просматривая свежие кадры кинохроники. Увы, писатель - не Господь Бог. К чему я? Сам не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

> Имеет ли вообще право на существование отдельный предмет литература?

Можно сказать, что не имеет: если литературу полагают возможным изучать в рамках школьной программы, почему бы в таком случае не включить в нее из соображений последовательности предметы, посвященные изучению остальных видов искусства?

Comment: Изучается изобразительное искусство, музыка. Как - другой вопрос.

Comment: Да мы же уже типа тут договорились. Литературу надо переименовать в Чтение и добавить отдельный предмет Развитие речи. Но поскольку всё это и так происходит на уроках (и чтение, и развитие речи) и все опытные учителя это и так знают, переименовывать большого смысла нет. Я для себя в этой условности разобрался, только не знаю, кому теперь Правильный ответ ставить (разваливается на две части).